# PHPUnit mock - call parent __get/__set/__isset

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, magic-methods

I am trying to mock a class that has inherited magic methods, but they are not getting implemented, and I have no idea how to fix it.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AnnoyingTestCase extends TestCase
{
    public function testNoAttributes()
    {
        $mock = $this->createMock(Child::class);
        $mock->attribute = 'value';

        $this->assertEquals($mock->attribute, null);
    }
}

class Base
{
    private $attributes = [];

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->attributes[$name] ?? null;
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->attributes[$name]);
    }
}

class Child extends Base
{
}
```

I would expect the `$mock->attribute` to have the value I assigned it, but it does not because `__set` is not being called.

If I try to use `->addMethods(['__get', '__set'])`, then it throws an exception: `Trying to set mock method "__get" with addMethods(), but it exists in class "Child". Use onlyMethods() for methods that exist in the class.`.
And yet adding a `var_dump` inside the `__set` method shows that it is not being called.

What can I do so that it has these methods?
Note that I am not looking to implement my own equivalent of these methods, I want the mock to have these original methods.

Comment: The whole point of a mock is that it doesn't take any of the existing behaviour of the class, but leaves all the functions empty so you can decide what they will return in specific cases.   What are you trying to test in this test? If you want to test the magic methods of the child class then you should make an actual instance of that class and assert that the class has the expected value afterwards. Right now it seems like you are testing a mock, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @DirkScholten I'm testing code that uses a class equivalent to the `Child` class above, and wanted to avoid writing boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this exact issue, but it may cause more harm than good.
The following code works:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Child::class)
    ->enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()
    ->getMock();
```

There is, however, the problem that this proxies ALL original method calls, and there is no way to narrow down the methods that you want to proxy. And the biggest - potentially broken constructor calls - is described here: [PHPUnit - MockBuilder::enableProxyingToOriginalMethods() breaks when original constructor calls public method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58096365/540394)