# PHPUnit - MockBuilder::enableProxyingToOriginalMethods() breaks when original constructor calls public method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to write a unit test that involves mocking a class whose constructor calls several public methods. Said public methods cannot be made private, at least for now. The same class also has magic methods that I want to keep unmocked (__get/__set/__isset), which is why I resorted to using `enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()` - I found no way to enable just those three original methods (source here: [PHPUnit - call parent __get/__set/__isset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58095070/540394)).
This makes the magic methods work, however it breaks the constructor.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExceptionTestCase extends TestCase
{
    public function testException()
    {
        $this->expectException(TypeError::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object');
        $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
            ->enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()
            ->getMock();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setBar();
    }

    public function setBar()
    {
    }
}
```

I would expect this to just work, since there is absolutely nothing out of the ordinary here, and yet it breaks for no apparent reason.
If the public method's visibility is set to private, then it works as expected, but I cannot do that in the real code.

How to fix this error without touching said public methods? Am I missing some MockBuilder config?

Answer (score 0):

[Test Proxies](https://thephp.cc/news/2014/03/phpunit-4-0-test-proxies), which is what `enableProxyingToOriginalMethods()` relates to, solve a problem that is probably not yours. And for solving this problem, the constructor needs to be executed with all required arguments.

Comment: The constructor has no arguments, as you can see, neither has the method called in constructor. It is the same as in my actual code. It breaks, just like code I provided here, which should be enough indication that something isn't right, since this is seemingly working code.